# Quintus how to set a simple background for a scene?

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to set an image as background for a scene but when i'm trying to change the background width and height to take the width and height of the full window the width and height of the background don't change

my code:

```
Q.scene('mainLevel', function(stage) {

 var BackGround = stage.insert(new Q.Sprite({
             asset: 'background1.png',
             cx:0,
             cy:0,
             x: 0,
             y: 0,
             w:Q.width,
             h:Q.height,
             type:Q.SPRITE_UI 
        }));
});
```

please any help and many thanks in advance...